# move_uploaded_file failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php

Actualmente quiero subir imágenes a mi servidor, pero me dice que no puede acceder a la ubicación:

Codigo php:

```
define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
    $target_path = "\uploads\\";
    $target_pathFile = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], SITE_ROOT.$target_pathFile)) {
        echo "El archivo ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
        " ha sido subido";
    } else{
        echo "Ha ocurrido un error, trate de nuevo!";
    }
```

error de salida:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(C:\xampp\htdocs\Punto_Venta\back_end\uploads\1.ico): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Punto_Venta\back_end\configuracion.php on line 7

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php3702.tmp' to 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Punto_Venta\back_end\uploads\1.ico' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Punto_Venta\back_end\configuracion.php on line 7
```

Antes funcionaba bien, pero hoy que lo probe me empezo a dejar ese mensaje.
Según yo todo esta bien.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta reemplazar la función `move_uploaded_file` por `copy` te dejo la documentación [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.copy.php)

Cuéntanos como te va.